# multiple tables with diff dataset in the same report

Tags: wpf, report, microsoft-reporting

I want to add two tables at the same report each one binding data from different table in database

I tried to make one dataset contains the two database tables and assign columns to different tables in the report as following:

```
rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            rptViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("reportDS", getData()));  //reportDS the dataset cretated with report

            rptViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"../../portifolioReport.rdlc";  

            rptViewer.RefreshReport();  

private DataTable getData()
    {
        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("select * from portifolio where patient_NID='"+NIDTxtBox4.Text+"'", con);
        SqlCeCommand cmd2 = new SqlCeCommand("select * from patients where NID='"+NIDTxtBox4.Text+"'", con);
        DataSet1.DataTable1DataTable dt = new DataSet1.DataTable1DataTable();
          SqlCeDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd);
        SqlCeDataAdapter dscmd2 = new SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd2);
          dscmd.Fill(dt);
          dscmd2.Fill(dt);
        return dt ;

    }
```

but there is a problem each row added in one table at report there is empty row was added in the other table

i'm using microsoft report ,wpf 
can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can join the select:

```
select
    *
from
    patients a
        inner join
    portifolio b
            on a.patient_NID = b.NID
```

This will bring the two tables together. You have other joins options, like: left join, right join, cross join(each one depend on your needs). I would need more details about the relation between(if existent) the information you are going to display.

Comment: when I use join the same problem exists but there are duplicated rows instead of empty rows

the report show patient data 
so the top table shows the basic data like name , age, gender
and the bottom one shows the patient log and prescription each visit